# Comparing 2 Sensors Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sensors

I have 2 data sets which are taken from 2 different Sensors. I have data of 15 Sec. 
Suppose Sensor A give 1182 reading in 15 sec and Sensor B give 1570 reading in the same time.
My question is how to compare these 2 data sets as one sensor give more values in same time.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to log the time (in microseconds) for each reading as it is recorded. Otherwise there's no "correct" way to do this without knowing the behavior of the sensors and making assumptions about when the samples occurred. If the start times for both sensors are roughly aligned and you assume equally spaced readings, then you can try to use `interp1` to re-interpolate them (either throwing out some readings or adding new ones).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- Both signals are measuring the same thing in the same units
- They start recording at exactly the same time
- They record at constant intervals
- And have unbiased and uncorrelated measurement errors
- They sample often enough that they catch all features of interest in the signal

It should be possible to combine the two measurements to get a higher overall measurement accuracy using [inverse variance weighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting).

Extending the answer above slightly to demonstrate this, the example code below takes two fake signals one with 10x higher measurement error than the other, up-samples them using `interp1` and combines them to get a slightly reduced measurement error.

For a real example you wont have the true signal available, so will have to estimate errors from information about sensor accuracy etc.

```
samples1 = 1182;        % No. of samples from sensor 1
samples2 = 1570;        % No. of samples from sensor 2
samplesTrue = 10000;    % No. of samples in 'true' signal (~continuous)

noise1 = 0.1;           % Std. dev of noise on signal 1
noise2 = 0.01;          % Std. dev of noise on signal 2

% Create samples; assuming both measurements start at exactly same time
t1=linspace(0,15,samples1);
t2=linspace(0,15,samples2);
tTrue = linspace(0, 15, samplesTrue);

% Create example measurement data
sglMeasure1 = sin(t1) + randn(size(t1)).*noise1;
sglMeasure2 = sin(t2) + randn(size(t2)).*noise2;
sglTrue = sin(tTrue);

% Plot true signal and measurements
figure(1),hold on
plot(tTrue, sglTrue);
plot(t1,sglMeasure1, '.');
plot(t2,sglMeasure2, '.');
hold off

% Interpolate data to high resolution, and get weighted sum of signals
sglInterp1 = interp1(t1, sglMeasure1, tTrue);
sglInterp2 = interp1(t2, sglMeasure2, tTrue);
signalWeights = [1/(noise1^2); 1/(noise2^2)];     % Inverse variance weight
signalWeights = signalWeights./sum(signalWeights);% Scale to sum to 1
sglInterpMean = sum(signalWeights'*[sglInterp1; sglInterp2], 1);

error1 = rms(sglTrue - sglInterp1);
error2 = rms(sglTrue - sglInterp2);
errorMean = rms(sglTrue - sglInterpMean);

disp(['error1: ' num2str(error1)]);
disp(['error2: ' num2str(error2)]);
disp(['errorMean: ' num2str(errorMean)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way will be using 'hold on'.

```
N1=1182; %number of samples of data1
N2=1570; %number of samples of data2

t1=linspace(0,15,N1); 
t2=linspace(0,15,N2);

data1=randn(1,N1); 
data2=randn(1,N2);

figure(1),hold on
plot(t1,data1)
plot(t2,data2)
hold off
```